# icacls give failed processing error in DOS for loop

Tags: batch-file, dos

So try this for loop on your Windows box

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"') do dir %b`

This works just fine for me but when I use the icacls command instead of dir I get an error that says icacls fails to process

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"') do icacls %b`

If I run icacls against any of the output one at a time it works just fine

`icacls c:\windows\ehome\ehrecvr.exe`

Also I echo the command just to make sure everything looks kosher and it

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"') do @echo icacls %b`

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the life of me, I can't figure out why that fails. But using `do call icacls %b` seems to get around the problem.

But service options are included in %b, and they cause icacls to fail because they are invalid options for icacls.

The simplest solution seems to be to switch to a batch file that calls a subroutine. The unwanted options are stripped by just processing %1.

Just to be safe, better to use `"tokens=1*"` in case `"` appears in any of the paths.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname="^|find /i /v "system32"') do call :doit %%b
exit /b

:doit
icacls %1
```

Comment: You didn't read Ed's post! [wmic corrupted stdout](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2927). `wmic` appends a carriage return character at the end, and your `CALL` removes it

Comment: dbenham,

Thanks for the feedback. I to cannot figure out why this fails but calling "do call icacls %b" does or I from a friend you can "do cmd.exe /c icacls %b" as well. Also this currently breaks with services that have options / switches, my friend suggested outputting to a text file with "for /f "tokens=2 delims='='" %a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"') do @echo %a>>c:\windows\temp\calcs.txt" then parsing that output with this line "for /f eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %a in (c:\windows\temp\calcs.txt) do cmd.exe /c cacls "%a"". So hope that helps others.